# How to change letters in a string in python

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I am trying to change the first character in a string to be uppercase. I approached it like this:

```
word = "dalmatian"
word[0] = word[0].upper() 
print word
```

However I produce this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Tom/Documents/coolone.py", line 3, in <module>
word[0] = word[0].upper() 
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't; Python strings are immutable. You have to create a new string:

```
word = word[0].upper() + word[1:]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [str.capitalize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize)

```
word = "dalmatian dalmatin"
word.capitalize()
Dalmatin dalmatin
```

or [str.title](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.title)

```
word = "dalmatian dalmatin"
word.title()
Dalmatin Dalmatin
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> "dalmatian".title()
'Dalmatian'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string method `capitalize` to do what you're looking for.

```
word = 'bla'
print word.capitalize()
Bla
```